# Safely delete foundationdb directory

Tags: directory, transactions, cascading-deletes, foundationdb

I want to delete a [foundationDB directory](https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/developer-guide.html#directories) and all it's contents. However, [DirectoryLayer::remove](https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/javadoc/com/apple/foundationdb/directory/DirectoryLayer.html#remove(com.apple.foundationdb.TransactionContext,java.util.List)) states:

> Warning: Clients that have already opened the directory might still insert data into its contents after it is removed.

Is there a way for me to transactionally remove a directory? I.e. after the delete transaction gets committed, the directory is completely gone. If there is a conflicting transaction that is adding to the directory, at most one succeeds?

Answer (score 1):

FoundationDB is implementing its directory as designated key, e.g. Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Key will be translated to something like

`Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Key`

thus, deleting a directory implies a clear range internally. This can be and is done transactionally. However, it is not possible to prevent additional keys, like

`Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/KeyAdditional`

being inserted after the directory is deleted, since the directory only exists conceptually, not internally.